# Nodemailer: Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nodemailer

Im trying to use nodemailer to send an email from a contact form. Below is all my code relating to nodemailer aswell as a screenshot of the error I get.
[image: error I receive]

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtppro.zoho.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
          user: '',
          pass: '',
        },
      });

      const date = new Date(Date.now());
      let contact = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: `"${this.data.name}" <${this.data.email}>`,
        to: this.data.staff,
        subject: `Contact Page Submission: ${this.data.subject}`,
        html: `
        <h1>New Contact Form Submission</h1>
    <span><b>From:</b> ${this.data.name} - ${this.data.email}</span><br>
    <span><b>Subject:</b> ${this.data.subject}</span><br>
    <span><b>To:</b> ${this.data.staff}</span><br>
    <span><b>Sent At:</b> ${date.toUTCString()}</span><br><br>
    <span><b>Message:</b></span>
    <p>${this.data.message}</p>
        `,
      });
```

When I try to load the page it throws the exception. When I remove the import statement it loads just like normal. This is all contained inside of a Vue.JS project. I have the latest version of nodemailer installed.

Comment: Might be circular dependencies in `nodemailer`

Comment: `nodemailer` runs only in Node. The screenshot shows you're trying to use it from the browser, which won't work.

Answer (score 2):

> `nodemailer` runs only in Node. The screenshot shows you're trying to
> use it from the browser, which won't work
> -- @tony19